# How to print index of for loop in FOLIUM MAP (Python)?

Tags: python, gis, modeling, folium

I am writing the following Python code to print numbers beside Folium ICON. I need these indices to be dynamic, meaning, I have a for loop, I want index value to be printed in the HTML line of the code.

```
for point in range(0, len(coordinates_st)):
    # showing number
    folium.Marker(location=[72.89, -124.59+2], icon=DivIcon(
        icon_size=(150, 36),
        icon_anchor=(7, 20),
        html='<div style="font-size: 18pt;">r{point}</div>',
    )).add_to(map_st)
```

I want to print number beside the HOME in the image below (loop indexing from for loop, not fixed 1, 2 as currently written in the code).

```
    for point in range(0, len(coordinates_st)):
        # showing number
        folium.Marker(location=[72.89, -124.59+2], icon=DivIcon(
            icon_size=(150, 36),
            icon_anchor=(7, 20),
            html='<div style="font-size: 18pt;">1, 2</div>',
        )).add_to(map_st)
```

[image: Current folium map]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the index can be displayed using f-string notation. Since the data is not presented, we can use geopandas data to display the usual markers for the cities of the world, with the index next to them.
characters.

```
import folium
import geopandas as gpd

geo_df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))

map_st = folium.Map(location=[50.08528, 14.46403], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=4)

for i,row in geo_df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker(location=[row.geometry.y, row.geometry.x+2],
                  icon=folium.DivIcon(
                      icon_size=(150, 36),
                      icon_anchor=(7, 20),
                      html=f'<div style="font-size: 12pt;">{i}</div>',
    )).add_to(map_st)
    folium.Marker(location=[row.geometry.y, row.geometry.x],icon=folium.Icon(color="black", icon="home"),
).add_to(map_st)
map_st
```

[image]

Comment: How can I rotate this ICON (I want to show these icons as water/spill icon; & don't want to use CustomDiv icon/ external image)?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't rotate the default marker, see SO for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263825/leaflet-custom-icon-marker-rotate-an-angle-the-transform-style-conflict). If my answer helped you, [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)`