# Question about mapping multiple position on world map in Folium

Tags: dataframe, folium

I am new to python and hoping I can get some direction on here. I'm having a hard time plotting multiple data points with marker on the world map in Folium.

The goal of this small project is to pinpoint each person on the map according to their longitude and latitude of their birthplace.

The popup will include their name, job title, and age. The error gave me was the error message is KeyError: 'lat, lon'. I have tried to create a csv file and build a dataFrame out of the data but seems like I'm not doing this correctly.

This is the dataframe I created:
[List in a dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1OB7.png)

[running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg14m.png)

KeyError: 'lat,lon'

Another way I tried was to create a csv file:

```
data = pd.read_csv(data)
```

and I used the same syntax as above:
[map=...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M74SB.png)

and it gave me the same error: Keyerror: 'lat,lon'. So I'm stuck now. Looking forward to some help. Thanks.

Comment: I think the example I gave in my previous response is applicable to your question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74471384/how-to-print-index-of-for-loop-in-folium-map-python).

Comment: So I found a method that manually input the location for each person but thats obviously a long way to do it. So i resorted back to the original method:m = folium.Map(['Lat', 'Lon'], zoom_start=2). But it gave me this error now:Location should consist of two numerical values, but 'Lat' of type <class 'str'> is not convertible to float.  Some reason it will not read the columns as Lat and Lon in location.